# Find the sum of the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\cos(2n-1)x}{(2n-1)!} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find the sum of the series:
>   $$
> S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\cos(2n-1)x}{(2n-1)!}
> $$

My attempt:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\cos(2n-1)x}{(2n-1)!}+i\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\sin(2n-1)x}{(2n-1)!}=\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(\cos x+i\sin x)^{2n+1}=\sin(\cos x+i\sin x)=\\
&=\sin(\cos x)\cos(i\sin x)+\cos(\cos x)\sin(i\sin x)
\end{aligned}
$$
And I wonder what to do next. How to separate my answer from $i$'s?

Comment: Use $\cos (i\sin x) = \cosh (\sin x)$, $\sin (i\sin x) = i\sinh (\sin x)$ and take the real part of both sides.

Comment: Do you mean $\cos((2n-1)x)$ or $x \cos(2n-1)$ ?

Comment: The former: $\cos((2n-1)x)$

Comment: Thanks to Gary's advice, I solved this problem. Thank you!